# I tried using 'AlarmManager' set the alarm, but did not succeed, what went wrong?

Tags: java, android

I followed the teaching tried to register the alarm, it should display "TEST" After five seconds,but it did not show any
*edit-
Although you want to do it for five seconds after the alarm, but actually they want to be executed in a fixed time every day
-*

I should have done all settings, is where it went wrong?

--- AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmClass" android:process=".abc">//What is the role of .abc?
    </receiver>
```

---MainActivity.java

```
    public void AddAlarm(View view){
    AlarmManager alm;
    PendingIntent pen;
    Calendar cal;

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy;MM;dd;HH;mm;ss");
    Date curDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()) ; 
    String str = formatter.format(curDate);
    String[] aArray = str.split(";");//Split time string

    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Integer.parseInt(aArray[0]), Integer.parseInt(aArray[1]), Integer.parseInt(aArray[2]), Integer.parseInt(aArray[3]), Integer.parseInt(aArray[4]), Integer.parseInt(aArray[5]) + 3);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlarmClass.class);
    alm = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    pen = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);//If I want to set multiple alarms should change the second argument?
    alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),pen);
}
```

---AlarmCless.java

```
public class AlarmClass extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive (Context context,Intent intent){
        Toast.makeText(context, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

---

And if I want to set multiple alarms, for example, five seconds and ten seconds later, passing different parameters
For example

Toast.makeText(context, teststring, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

But 'teststring' appear differently, how do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the action tag for the receiver in `Manifest.xml`

```
 <receiver android:name=".AlarmClass" android:process=".abc">
   <action android:name="your_action" />
 </receiver>
```

Here `android:process=".abc"` specifies the name of the process in which the broadcast receiver should run.
Declare an intent for sending the broadcast.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent("your_action");
    alm = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Declare PendingIntent with its own notification id, bacause no two notification should has the same id, it they has the same id they get overrided.

```
pen = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,notification_id,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);//If I want to set multiple alarms should change the second argument?
```

Since you need to send the broadcast after 5sec form now use `System.currentTimeMillis()+5000`

```
alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+5000,pen);
```

If you want to send another broadcast after 10sec then follow same above procedure but with different notification_id and use System.currentTimeMillis()+10000  instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()+5000`

Comment: Thank you: D,
I'm trying, but I fixed narrative about the number of seconds, I found 'after five seconds' is not quite correct description

Comment: This works! :D thanks!
By the way, app crashes after five seconds the display looks "Toast.makeText (context," TEST ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show ();" is not correct?

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: I do not know, which side I check the error message? He just shows "Sorry, app has stopped."

Comment: Error message will be visible in the logcat window.

Comment: I find 'logcat', but he has been updated with new row, too fast, I do not know to check which error message

Comment: try to remove android:process=".abc" for the receiver in the manifest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79191/discussion-between-kartheek-and-am031447).

Comment: Oh, I found my mistake, I 'AlarmClass' forget to remove the extra codes,
Remove android: ". Abc"! Process = is effective, it worked Thank you very much!
: D ,But it is my fault, I'm sorry